# How to upload image on wordpress server by webservice with new "uploads" directory in iphone programming?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, wordpress, web-services

I need to upload image by a **webservice** which is of wordpress server ..

Image is not uploaded because of **wordpress** structure ..

This is my basic code for image upload in **iPhone** ..

```
NSData *myData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([self.img image]);
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
NSString *urlString = @"http://xyzabc.com/iphone/upload.php";
NSString *filename = @"filename";
request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myData]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString;
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

It returns whole page in **returnString** !!!

I need only one response is a path of image that I uploaded..

Any one have idea of that?

Comment: Wordpress has its own api http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API that you can post and upload images and get a proper response. and you should be fitting your xcode to the response and not the other way around as it has a very structured api that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a wordpress developer. You can use this code in your web service.

```
if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}
$overrides = array( 'test_form' => false);
$file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['image_url'], $overrides);
$file['url'];

$content = $file['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks @pulkit-agarwal but the work is done bcz replies comes after 4 months, may other will get help from your answer.

Comment: I am not wordpress dev. but accepting the answer. Hope this will help other